# preg match for registration script php

Tags: php, authentication, preg-match, registration

Im trying to do some preg match to make my script more secure, but whatever i type in username/realname i get error... where am i going wrong here?

```
        $unpreg = $_POST["username"];
        $empreg = $_POST["email"];
        $rnpreg = $_POST["realname"];

        $error = false;
        if(preg_match("/[^\p{L}\p{N}_\-\.]+/iu','",$unpreg) || (filter_var($empreg, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL)) || (preg_match("/[^\p{L}\s]+/u",$rnpreg))) {

            $error = true;
        }
        if(!$error) {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO Users (UserName, Email, Password,Real_Name) VALUES (:username, :email, :password, :realname)";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->bindParam(':username',$unpreg);
            $stmt->bindParam(':realname',$rnpreg);
            $stmt->bindParam(':email', $empreg);
            $stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
            $stmt->execute();

            $message = 'Successfully created new user';

        } 
        else {

            $message = 'Error, Something went wrong.';
        }
```

Basically for unpreg i want to allow a-ö 0-9 -_ and for rnpreg a-ö - and space

EDIT: if i remove `(filter_var($empreg, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL))` it works... how do i implemend that without breaking it?

Comment: Why the single quotes and a comma in `"/[^\p{L}\p{N}_\-\.]+/iu','"`? Use just `"/[^\p{L}\p{N}_.-]+/iu"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew okey, tanks but i still got the same problem im afraid

Comment: `filter_var` in your case does not return a boolean, just a cleaned email. You must have wanted `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yea i realized, but the problem still persists with that aswell :(

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew (!filter_var($empreg, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) works tho, but is that a correct way of doing it?

Comment: It seems that it is right acc. to your code logic. You return an error if `preg_match`s find matches.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew both should work the same, but dunno what's customary to use.. :) Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `','` in the first regex are an error and must be removed. Then, you need o use `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL` while you need `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` to *validate* the email. And you need to negate the `filter_var` since you follow negated logics in your `if`.

Use

```
if(preg_match("/[^\p{L}\p{N}_.-]+/iu",$unpreg) || !filter_var($empreg, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) || preg_match("/[^\p{L}\s]+/u",$rnpreg))
```

So, the error will be returned if a `[^\p{L}\p{N}_.-]+` pattern is found, or the email is not valid or if `[^\p{L}\s]+` pattern is matched.